# R.O.C of $\sum_{0}^{\infty} a_n x^n$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

Consider the power series $\sum_{n =0}^{\infty} a_n x^n$. Where $a_0= 0$ and $a_n = \frac{sin n!}{n!}$ for $n \geq 1$. Let R be the radius of convergence of the power series. Then

1. $R \geq 1$
2. $R \geq 2π$
3. $R \leq 4π$
4. $R \geq π$

My Attempt:

$1\over R$ = $lim_{n \to \infty}(a_n)^{1\over n}$ = $lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ = $lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\frac{sin (n+1)!}{(n+1)!} \over \frac{sin n!}{n!}\right)$ = $1\over1$ = $1$. So options 1,2,4 are true.

Comment: You (erroneously) get $R=1$, then erroneously deduce the correct answer 1,2, and 4.

Comment: @GEdgar, Yes I was wrong. I think all options are true, it is because given series is everywhere convergent. Please clear my doubt.

Comment: Option 3 is false.  The other are true.

Comment: Thanks. It is very trivial but I understand it very late.

Comment: |a_n|≤ 1/n! It follows that R=infinity

Answer (score 1):

Where does the $\frac 11$ comes from ? are you sure you did not confuse with $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\to 1$ when $x\to 0$.

But here $n!\to\infty$ not zero.

The ratio test gives you $\dfrac{\sin((n+1)!)}{\sin(n!)}\times\dfrac 1{n+1}$

Show that $\dfrac{\sin(mx)}{\sin(x)}$ is a finite sum of $\cos(kx)$ thus bounded, and conclude regarding the ratio test.

Answer (score 0):

since
$|\sin(n!)| < 1$ and Stirling's approximation tells us that  $$n! \sim \left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\sqrt{2\pi n}.$$
hence
$|{{\sin (n!)}\over {n!}}|^{1/n}
<\frac{1}{n/e}
\to 0
$
so the series converges
everywhere.

Comment: I'm confusing with the fact that it is converges everywhere so all options are true.